# Material Desigl Light (MDL) - Discrete slider, How to use as range slider

Tags: material-design

[image]

I am using https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#sliders-section for developing range slider. But material design providing only one way sliding. I attached one image for my range slider requirement.

Please help me, how I can range sliding option and get selected range min & max value into div?

Comment: Hey, Did you got solution for the problem. I also have the same requirement, it will be great if you can share the answer for the same.